# Uploading files with visualforce page and attached it the record row

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have a visualeforce page with a pageblocktable, and a link 'Add row' to add row, but how can I save this row as a record in my object! and attach a file to each column, for example 'Food Expenses' I have to upload the bill

Here is my VF:

```
<apex:page controller="AP005ManageListController" tabstyle="Expenses__c">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.styles, 'RHstyles.css')}"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Bulk Account Create">
<apex:pageblockSection title="Traveling Information" >
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper" id="wtable">
     <apex:column headerValue="Client">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Client__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Project">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Project__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Date">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Date__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Food/Meal Expenses">
        <apex:inputText value="{!wrapper.acc.Food_Expenses__c}"/>
     </apex:column>

     <apex:column headerValue="Phone Expenses">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Phone_Expenses__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
    <!-- <apex:column headerValue="File">
    <apex:inputFile value="{!wrapper.a.body}" filename="{!wrapper.a.name}"/>
    </apex:column>  -->
    </apex:pageblockSection>
     <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!delWrapper}" rerender="wtable">
           <apex:param name="toDelIdent" value="{!wrapper.ident}" assignTo="{!toDelIdent}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
     </apex:column>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRows}" rerender="wtable">
     <apex:param name="addCount" value="1" assignTo="{!addCount}"/>
  </apex:commandButton>

  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
```

And my controller :

```
public class AP005ManageListController
 {
  public List<ExpenseWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
  public List<AttachmentWrapper> attach{get; set;}
  public static Integer toDelIdent {get; set;}
  public static Integer addCount {get; set;}
  private Integer nextIdent=0;
  public AP005ManageListController()
{
 wrappers=new List<ExpenseWrapper>();
 attach= new List<AttachmentWrapper>();
 attach.add(new AttachmentWrapper());
 wrappers.add(new ExpenseWrapper(nextIdent++));
}
public void delWrapper()
{
 Integer toDelPos=-1;
 for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
 {
 if (wrappers[idx].ident==toDelIdent)
{
 toDelPos=idx;
 }
 }
  if (-1!=toDelPos)
 {
  wrappers.remove(toDelPos);
 }
 }
    public void addRows() {
    for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++){
    wrappers.add(new ExpenseWrapper(nextIdent++));
    }
    }
    public PageReference save()
    {
    List<Expense__c> expes=new List<Expense__c>();
    List<Attachment> att=new List<>(Attachment);
    for (ExpenseWrapper wrap : wrappers){
    for(AttachmentWrapper attWrap :attach ){
    att.add(attWrap.exp);
    }
     expes.add(wrap.exp);
  } 
      insert expes;
     return new PageReference('/' +   Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Expense__c').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
      }
      public class ExpenseWrapper
      {
      public Expense__c exp{get; private set;}
      public Integer ident {get; private set;}

      public ExpenseWrapper(Integer inIdent)
      {
      ident=inIdent;
      exp=new Expense__c();
      }
}
public class AttachmentWrapper {
public Expense__c exp {get;set;}
public Attachment att {get;set;}
public AttachmentWrapper(Expense__c exp, Attachment att){
    this.exp = exp;
    if(att!= null){
        this.att = att;
    } else {
        this.att = new Attachment(parentId = this.att.Id);
    }
}
}
}
```

How can I put the 'upload file' button to upload a number of files and attached it to the rercord

Comment: can u put a meaningful title for your question please?

Comment: highfive see my edit

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a wrapper class to have both the Expense__c record and it's attachment record in the pageblocktable. Change your current wrapper to something like this:

```
public class ExpenseWrapper
{
        public Expense__c exp{get; private set;}
        public Attachment att {get;set;}
        public Integer ident {get; private set;}

        public ExpenseWrapper(Integer inIdent)
        {
            ident=inIdent;
            exp=new Expense__c();
            att=new Attachment();
        }
}
```

The list you display in the pageblocktable should then be a `List<ExpenseWrapper>` instead of a `List<Expense__c>`.

Then create a file upload button inside the pageblocktable like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrapperRecord" >           
    <apex:column headerValue="Date">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapperRecord.m.Date__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Food/Meal Expenses">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapperRecord.m.Food_Expenses__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Phone Expenses">
        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapperRecord.m.Phone_Expenses__c}"/>
    </apex:column>              
    <apex:column headerValue="File">
        <apex:inputFile value="{!wrapperRecord.a.body}" filename="{!wrapperRecord.a.name}"/>
    </apex:column>          
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Lastly, don't forget to update both the Expense__c records and the Attachments in your save method (updating the parentId on the Attachment records with the new Expense__c id's before saving them). Something like this:

```
public PageReference save()
{
    List<Expense__c> expes=new List<Expense__c>();
    List<Attachment> attToInsert=new List<>(Attachment);
    for (ExpenseWrapper wrap : wrappers){
        expes.add(wrap.exp);
    } 
    insert expes;

    Integer counter = 0;
    for(Expense__c exp : expes){

        if(exp.Id != null){
            if(wrappers[counter].att != null){
                wrappers[counter].att.parentId = exp.Id;
                attToInsert.add(wrappers[counter].a);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    insert attToInsert;

    return new PageReference('/' +   Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Expense__c').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
}
```

Comment: What is the wrapperList herE??

Comment: it's the name of the List<AttachmentWrapper>

Comment: Hey guy!! I edited my code but still doesnt work! see edit

Comment: what's the error you're getting? also the top part of the VF page seems to be missing.

Comment: I don't know how to combine two wrapper classes, cuz I already have a wrapper class to add rows dynamically

Comment: You should indeed combine them. The Expense__c record is already in both wrappers. If you add the public Integer ident {get; private set;} to the AttachmentWrapper, you can use that wrapper for both capturing the attachment and for adding new rows. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Check please my save method! is it correct? cuz it's not working

Comment: if something's not working, pls try to add some explanation as to what is not working. I now have to guess what's going wrong. Updated my answer with a save method (and also changes to the wrapper class). This should be enough to point you in the right direction. If you don't get it right, it might be wise studying some more APEX literature before taking on this slightly advanced logic.