# How to add a field in Salesforce using Standard field Types/using Visualforce, so that we can Attach a file from Computer with it?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, commandbutton

I am working on designing custom views using Visual-force.
Here I want to create a field that ask user to choose a file from Computer. 
Like in below screenshot:[image]

But I didn't see any field type in Sales-force standard field types that can allow us to get file from Computer on click of button **Browse**

Is there any way to create this type of field in salesforce?

Do I have to use some custom fields or buttons to do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Text Area(rich).

Comment: Text Area does not cover/solve this issue.

Comment: You have to save that file as blob in text area(rich)

Comment: Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a specific field type that you can use for this. It is possible to attach a file to a record using Visualforce page with a custom Apex controller which will allow the user to browse the files on their drives.

This [Question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35167/uploading-files-with-visualforce-page-and-attached-it-the-record-row) explain how this can be done using Visualforce and Apex.